# Django testing for templates loaded via template tags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-testing

I am writing a suite of tests for an app.

In a number of places I use Django's handy "assertTemplateUsed". This works for all templates except, as far as I see for templates loaded via template tags (as inclusion_tag objects).

Is there an alternative way I assert template is used, when it is loaded via a template tag? I can of course check for strings in the template, but check for use of the template would be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try catching the [`template_rendered` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.test.signals.template_rendered), which is available during testing.

From the docs:

```
django.test.signals.template_rendered

Sent when the test system renders a template. This signal is not emitted during normal operation of a Django server – it is only available during testing.

Arguments sent with this signal:

sender
    The Template object which was rendered.
template
    Same as sender
context
    The Context with which the template was rendered.
```